# Best pattern for controller passing lists within lists

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Using a controller to build data to pass to a JSP, what is the best way to design it to allow looping within loops. In straight JSP, you would just do queries within the loops. But with MVC we're not supposed to do that.

In the jsp, I need to create something like this:

```
Business
  Project 1
    Item
    Item
  Project 2
    Item
    Item
    Item
  Project 3
    Item
Business 2
...
```

What structure do I need to create in the controller? A List isn't going to do it. And the list would need to contain different object types. How do I structure the loops in the JSP?

Does a resource exist online that describes these kinds of patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use something like

```
class Business
  String businessName;
  List<Projects> projects

class Projects
  String projectName;
  List<Item>

class Item
  String itemName;
```

And pass in request.setAttribute("business", BusinessObject)

then iterate over the attributes .

```
<c:forEach var="projects" items="${business.projects}">
  <tr><td>${projects.name}<td>
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${projects.item}">
     <tr><td>${item.name}<td>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Consider read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208671/nested-cforeach-in-jstl)